# Can't play my .apk on Pico VR due to Copyright Verification error

Tags: unity, android, virtual-reality

I’m learning to use Unity to create VR applications for my company to use internally. I created an app that worked great on the Quest 2, and decided to try to do this for Pico as well. I followed a tutorial for Pico, and was able to get a working .apk file and transfer it to my Pico Neo 3 Pro using ManageXR (MDM).

I was able to view my app in VR for about 10 seconds, just long enough to see it was working – but then Pico automatically closed it and displayed this message: This app didn’t pass “Copyright Verification”. Go to “App Store” to check if you’ve purchased this app and restart it. Go to “app Store”? [Exit] [Enable] I pressed Enable, and expectedly the app store said “No information available” I’ve already created a Pico developer account, and got an app ID, which I included in the .apk. I don’t want this app to be publicly accessible, I just want to explore VR for internal use.

I want to iterate & develop. Any ideas how to get past this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem, but unchecking the User Entitlement Check box does not change anything. Is there any other solution?

Comment: @MPoups That sounds like a question you should post by clicking the "Ask Question" button. You can include a link to this page for context, and also add more details about how your app or the symptoms you're observing differ from the case that was solved here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to PXR_SDK (on top ribbon of Unity, next to Windows), click Platform Settings, make sure User Entitlement Check[?] box is unchecked.

This fixed it for me - thank you Luis Z!